# How to insert blank lines in PDF?

Tags: itext

I am creating a PDF using iText. I want to insert blank lines between paragraphs and tables.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried actually inserting blank strings?  Literally `" "`.

Comment: @Beemer: That's the first thing I tried as well, but the blank strings just don't show up.  I tried adding them as bare strings and as new empty paragraphs.  The solution I added below is the first thing I found that works.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard; I guess iText ignores any empty or white-space string.  Good to know.  Thanks!

Comment: Just insert "\n", should do the trick.

Comment: How to do in case of PDFAWriter?

Answer (score 111):

You can trigger a newline by inserting `Chunk.NEWLINE` into your document.  Here's an example.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        // create a new document
        Document document = new Document( PageSize.A4, 20, 20, 20, 20 );
        PdfWriter.getInstance( document, new FileOutputStream( "HelloWorld.pdf" ) );

        document.open();

        document.add( new Paragraph( "Hello, World!" ) );
        document.add( new Paragraph( "Hello, World!" ) );

        // add a couple of blank lines
        document.add( Chunk.NEWLINE );
        document.add( Chunk.NEWLINE );

        // add one more line with text
        document.add( new Paragraph( "Hello, World!" ) );

        document.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Below is a screen shot showing part of the PDF that the code above produces.

[image: Hello PDF with blank lines inserted]

Comment: `public static final Chunk NEWLINE = new Chunk("\n");`.  Jes was right, as are you.  BTW:  add(new Chunk("\n\n\n") should produce three new lines, though I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 29):

And to insert blank line between tables you can use these both methods

```
table.setSpacingBefore();      

table.setSpacingAfter();
```

Comment: At least in version 5.1.1 of iText#, these methods don't seem to exist; however there are properties: `SpacingBefore` and `SpacingAfter`.

Comment: This is much more useful than `Chunk.NEWLINE` if you are using tables.

Comment: iText7 Table neither has setSpacingBefore/After methods nor a such named constant in Property.class.

Answer (score 18):

You can use "\n" in Paragraph

```
document.add(new Paragraph("\n\n"));
```

Comment: This is the only working solution in iText7

Answer (score 8):

You can try a blank phrase:

```
document.add(new Phrase("\n"));
```

Comment: Phrase class does not exist anymore in iText7. Use new Paragraph("\n").

Answer (score 5):

You can add Blank Line throw `PdfContentByte` class in `itextPdf`. As shown below:

```
package com.pdf.test;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import com.itextpdf.text.Chunk;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class Ranvijay {

    public static final String RESULT = "d:/printReport.pdf";

    public void createPdf(String filename) throws Exception {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                new FileOutputStream(filename));
        document.open();

        Font bold = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8f, Font.BOLD);
        Font normal = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8f, Font.NORMAL);
        PdfPTable tabletmp = new PdfPTable(1);
        tabletmp.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        tabletmp.setWidthPercentage(100);
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
        float[] colWidths = { 45, 55 };
        table.setWidths(colWidths);
        String imageUrl = "http://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/logo/2x/googleplus_color_33-99ce54a16a32f6edc61a3e709eb61d31.png";
        Image image2 = Image.getInstance(new URL(imageUrl));
        image2.setWidthPercentage(60);
        table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        table.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        table.getDefaultCell().setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_TOP);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
        cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        cell.addElement(image2);
        table.addCell(cell);
        String email = "ranvijay9286@gmail.com";
        String collectionDate = "09/09/09";
        Chunk chunk1 = new Chunk("Date: ", normal);
        Phrase ph1 = new Phrase(chunk1);

        Chunk chunk2 = new Chunk(collectionDate, bold);
        Phrase ph2 = new Phrase(chunk2);

        Chunk chunk3 = new Chunk("\nEmail: ", normal);
        Phrase ph3 = new Phrase(chunk3);

        Chunk chunk4 = new Chunk(email, bold);
        Phrase ph4 = new Phrase(chunk4);

        Paragraph ph = new Paragraph();
        ph.add(ph1);
        ph.add(ph2);
        ph.add(ph3);
        ph.add(ph4);

        table.addCell(ph);
        tabletmp.addCell(table);
        PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
        canvas.saveState();
        canvas.setLineWidth((float) 10 / 10);
        canvas.moveTo(40, 806 - (5 * 10));
        canvas.lineTo(555, 806 - (5 * 10));
        canvas.stroke();
        document.add(tabletmp);
        canvas.restoreState();
        PdfPTable tabletmp1 = new PdfPTable(1);
        tabletmp1.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        tabletmp1.setWidthPercentage(100);

        document.add(tabletmp1);

        document.close();
    }

    /**
     * Main method.
     * 
     * @param args
     *            no arguments needed
     * @throws DocumentException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Ranvijay().createPdf(RESULT);
        System.out.println("Done Please check........");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
document.add(new Paragraph(""))
```

It is ineffective above,must add a blank string, like this:

```
document.add(new Paragraph(" "));
```

Comment: Has no effect in iText7. Use new Paragraph("\n").

Answer (score 2):

You can add empty line ;

```
 Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
 // add one empty line
  addEmptyLine(p, 1);
 // add 3 empty line
  addEmptyLine(p, 3);


private static void addEmptyLine(Paragraph paragraph, int number) {
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
      paragraph.add(new Paragraph(" "));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Has no effect in iText7. Use new Paragraph("\n").

Answer (score 2):

You can also use

```
document.add(new Paragraph());
document.add(new Paragraph());
```

before seperator if you are using either it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using:

```
document.add( Chunk.NEWLINE );
```

use this:

```
document.add(new Paragraph(""));
```

it makes small space

Comment: add space while creating new paragraph document.add(new Paragraph(" "));

Comment: Chunk class does not exist anymore in iText7. Use new Paragraph("\n").

Answer (score 1):

directly use

```
paragraph.add("\n");
```

to add an empty line.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add blank lines after a table and I manage it adding many divs as I need it with a css style with padding-top set it up, like this. I've used a template engine (underscore) to loop through the number of lines I need to add.

```
 <% var maxRow = 30; var pos = items.models.length; %>
 <% for( pos; pos < maxRow; pos++ ){ %>
       <div class="blankRow"></div>
 <% }; %>
```

My css file:

```
 .blankRow:{ padding-top: 15px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted this in another question, but I find using tables with iTextSharp offers a great level of precision.

```
document.Add(BlankLineDoc(16));

public static PdfPTable BlankLineDoc(int height)
{
    var table = new PdfPTable(1) {WidthPercentage = 100};
    table = BlankLineTable(table, height);
    return table;
}

public static PdfPTable BlankLineTable(PdfPTable table, int height, int border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER)
{
    var cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" "))
    {
        Border = border,
        Colspan = table.NumberOfColumns,
        FixedHeight = height
    };
    table.AddCell(cell);
    return table;
}
```

BlankLineTable can be used directly when working with tables