# NullElement Pattern for IText Element

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Is there a way to return an **com.lowagie.text.Element** by a method which does not change the contents of **my com.lowagie.text.Document** if added to it?

(In other words for people searching the question via Google: An empty iText Element)

The question is kind of related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158336/how-to-insert-blank-lines-in-pdf).

Comment: (1.) All classes in packages that mention my name (I am the Lowagie that originally created `com.lowagie.text.*` classes) are obsolete. You are using a version of iText that is no longer supported. It has technical as well as legal issues. (2.) Your question is unclear. You can create empty `Chunk`, `Phrase`,... elements, can't you? What is the problem with those empty elements? Did you try `VerticalPositionMark`?

Comment: I am using the LGPL version 2.1.7.
I will have a look if Chunk or Phrase Elements do the job. Thanks for your kind reply.

Comment: Talking about legal issues, it should be fine, if I mention that I used iText in my software credentials right? 
Visiting the iText website I even do not know how much a license would cost.

Comment: Mentioning iText in the software credentials isn't sufficient. Please read the legal section of [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html) for more info (it's a free ebook).